# WebStorm JavaScript live template - deciding where the cursor will be

Tags: javascript, webstorm

I've created a JavaScript live template which I use a lot in WebStorm:

```
console.log('$PARAM$ -> ', $PARAM$);
```

It helps me type this kind of lines faster:

```
console.log('nextProps -> ', nextProps);
```

However as it starts on the first `$PARAM$` I don't get autocomplete. Is there a way to get the cursor to the second `$PARAM$` while keeping the duplicated text adding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use 2 variables instead of 1
2. Reorder them -- 2nd one should be filled first
3. Tell IDE to auto-copy 2nd variable into 1st
4. Tell IDE to ignore 1st variable if it has value (which it will because of #3)

[image]

```
console.log('$PARAM1$ -> ', $PARAM2$);
```