# WebStorm - Live templates - indicate the order of focusing the same variable

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am interested in if there is a mean to indicate where the writing the variable name should start

e.g if I call this live template:

```
console.log('$TEXT$', $TEXT$);
             ^
```

It will start writing from the first TEXT variable.

I want to start writing from the second one:

```
console.log('$TEXT$', $TEXT$);
                      ^
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Indicate the order of focusing the same variable

You cannot do that: each variable is processed only once.

**The solution** is to apply a *simple workaround*: create an additional/intermediate variable that will automatically get the same value from the first variable and arrange them in the desired order.

1. Create a new variable and give it different name (e.g. `$VAR$`):

   ```
   console.log('$TEXT$', $VAR$);$END$
   ```

   *NOTE: I've also added `$END$` to denote final cursor position*
2. Click on the `Edit variables` button.
3. Rearrange variables in desired order (using `Up` / `Down` buttons on the right side).
4. Assign default value for `TEXT` variable: make it to accept the value that you will enter for `VAR` variable.
5. Also check the `Skip if defined` checkbox if you do not plan to edit the `TEXT` value while filling the variables.

[image]

**Result:** only 1 place to enter variable name (code completion is available if needed) and the entered value is automatically copied into the text field (which you can still edit later once you're done with expanding the template).

[image]

Related StackOverflow questions:

- [WebStorm - Live templates - indicate the order of focusing the same variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630973/webstorm-live-templates-indicate-the-order-of-focusing-the-same-variable)
- [WebStorm JavaScript live template - deciding where the cursor will be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38522819/webstorm-javascript-live-template-deciding-where-the-cursor-will-be)

Comment: Exactly what I needed. +1

Comment: Really really great time saver. Having the string first helps so much when logging many items quickly when reading browser console.