# WebStorm live template auto complete within string

Tags: webstorm

Created the following JS live template:

```
 console.log('$var$ -> ', $var$);
```

That can generate this:

```
 console.log('response ->', response);
```

I would love to have auto completion within the string. OR have me edit the second `$var$` and make the first one be the same.

Any way to accomplish that?

Playing with "edit variables" `completion()` and `smartCompletion()` did not seem to auto complete the local variables.

Comment: *"OR have me edit the second $var$ and make the first one be the same."* https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634968/783119

Answer (score 0):

OK, choosing the **JsArrayVariable()** expression in the "edit variables" modal seem to be working as mentioned in the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-template-variables.html).

Couldn't find it at first as the docs's description of JsArrayVariable is not very clear:

> JsArrayVariable:  Returns JavaScript array name.

IMHO, a better description would be "Auto-select from a list of scope variables".