# How to make a muti cursor in a Live Templates in PhpStorm

Tags: php, templates, phpstorm

How to make a multi cursor in a Live Templates in PhpStorm?

Just like `var_dump("|:",$|)`. I've tried to make it with `var_dump("$END$:",$END$)` but failed.

Comment: Hold down alt whilst clicking

Comment: Use multiple variables and assign result of one to another -- it will "simulate" multi carets -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41634968/783119 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/38523228/783119